# set number of pages on gridview

Tags: asp.net, performance, linq, gridview

I am trying to populate records on a gridview depending on the result of two linq methods:
`GetRecords(string SearchCriteria, int skip, int take)` 
which provides me the ammount of rows i´m going to show into the gridview, and
`CountRecords(string SearchCriteria)`
Which provides me with the total `count` of the records.

First I get the number of records by using the `CountRecords` method, and then I calculate the number of pages to make the user know how many pages the gridview has, but the property gridview.PageCount is read only. How can i set the ammount of pages the gridview is going to have, without getting all the records (they're about 300000, so i cannot afford this option)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set virtual count. Set AllowCustomPaging to true.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxdbyxtc.aspx